# how to clear an `AutoValue` property via an `AutoValue.Builder`

Tags: java, code-generation, builder, auto-value

I have an `AutoValue` with an `Optional` property. The `AutoValue` also has a `Builder`. Is there a way to use the `Builder` to clear the `Optional` property? I could not find anything about it in the `AutoValue.Builder` [documentation](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/main/value/userguide/builders-howto.md). **If this is not possible, is there a suggested work around?**

Example below:

```
package com.google.sandbox;

import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;
import java.util.Optional;

@AutoValue
  public abstract static class MainMessage {

    public static Builder builder() {
      return new AutoValue_MainClass_MainMessage.Builder();
    }

    public abstract Optional<Integer> val();

    public abstract Builder toBuilder();

    /** Builder for MainMessage. */
    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {

      public abstract Builder setVal(int value);

      public abstract Builder clearVal(); // This causes a compiler error.

      public abstract MainMessage build();
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
[AutoValueBuilderNoArg] Method without arguments should be a build method returning com.google.sandbox.MainClass.MainMessage, or a getter method with the same name and type as a property method of com.google.sandbox.MainClass.MainMessage, or fooBuilder() where foo() or getFoo() is a property method of com.google.sandbox.MainClass.MainMessage
      public abstract Builder clearVal();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a second `setVal` method with an `Optional<Integer>` parameter, then call that with `Optional.empty()`. If you don't want that to be part of the public API, you could make it package-private and have a public method that calls it:

```java
  public abstract static class Builder {
    public abstract Builder setVal(int value);
    abstract Builder setVal(Optional<Integer> value);
    public Builder clearVal() {
      setVal(Optional.empty());
    }
    public abstract MainMessage build();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any plan for AutoValue to support this natively?

Comment: Not currently, but we could document how to use `Optional` a bit more clearly, including ideas like the answer here.